# How to set gujarati fonts on Android in Phonegap

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, fonts

Phonegap is all about html,css & js. So I need to set the font face in html / css. I want to show some gujarati fonts in my html page. It works on browser of my desktop. But this page is nothing to show in my Android Device.

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="../jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
<script src="../jquery.mobile/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>

<!-- Cordova -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="../js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @font-face {
            font-family: centurySchoolbook;
            src: url(../fonts/Shruti.ttf)format("opentype");      
        }
       body {
           font-family: centurySchoolbook;
           font-size:30px;
       }
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="font-family: 'centurySchoolbook';">શ્રુતિ ફોન્ટ શું છે અને તે કેવી રીતે વાપરવો ? </div>

</body>
</html>
```

cordova : cordova-2.5.0

android: 4.1.2

I had changed this line `src: url(/fonts/Shruti.ttf)format("opentype");` to `src: url(/fonts/Shruti.ttf)format("truetype");` & also used as `src: url(/fonts/Shruti.ttf)`. But there is no way to working on my android device. Can any one know how to solve this issue? Any help would be appreciated!!

It shows gujarati font on samsung tab2 but not showing in any of devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do that you have to generate webfont for Gujarati font. As your font is installed in your local desktop its working fine.

To generate web font look at this url:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Phonegap apps are just like local web pages, so you should be able to set fonts just as like you set one for a website you do. Say for example, I can use a Google font in my app by just linking as they have [documented](http://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace%3aquickUse/Family%3a).

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jolly+Lodger' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And create a CSS definition for the same.

```
h1 { font-family: ‘Metrophobic’, Arial, serif; font-weight: 400; }
```

But this involves a network request at app loading. So, a better way is to have the font file in your app directory, and create the CSS definition from it.

```
@font-face {
     font-family: "customfont";
     src: url("./XXXX.ttf") format("opentype");   
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I had already used this.but its not working.

Comment: Then it is most likely that, this is not a font issue, but a language support issue you have with your device. Please check if you could display any `Gujarati` text on your device.

Comment: had tried to load any gujarati website in android device using webview in my layout. it shows perfectly but my html file is not showing gujarati words.